# How to deploy TFS2010 Custom Policies without need to install it in every client machine

Tags: policy

I've been studying TFS Custom Policies, and I'me very disappointed with deploy. How can we guarantee that a new developer, that could be or not at same place, will have all custom policies defined for some project installed on his Machine?

In my thoughts would be possible to define a new policy at TFS2010 Project, and when a new developer were associated to this project, in a new checkin he would be asked for download all policies applied.

Do you think that it is possible?

Comment: Not to take away from your question - because distributing check-in policies is *exceptionally* important (and a +1 for it), but it sounds like you want a check-in policy to make sure the check-in policies are installed...

Comment: If you don't trust your developers to install the right policies then consider whether you trust them enough to accept their code. (And policies can always be bypassed – by design – again coming down to trust.)

Comment: Richard, it'snt a matter of trust. We just want to automate creation of a productive and organized environment, instead depend on ours developers hands. They shouldn't have to be worried about environment, just about their codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can distributing check-in policies across your team using **Install downloaded custom components**, see the following link

http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2010/12/distributing-check-in-policies-across.html